# C# Call node js socket from c# back backend code

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a socket.io server that is communicating with a socket.io javascript client via a website.
Now i want to send data to that socket from my C# backend code .I have checked some open library

[SocketIO4Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SocketIO4Net.Client) And

[H.Socket.IO](https://github.com/HavenDV/H.Socket.IO/)

but booth are giving error is there any other open library that will help me.

Comment: You either do not have a route between the client and server or the connection is failing.  the libraries you are using should work.  Are you using HTTP or HTTPS (secure). More than likely the HTTPS is failing due to a TLS issue.

Comment: @jdweng yes i am using HTTPS  and H.Socket.IO giving 404 bed request but https://dotnetfiddle.net/FWMpQ3/ live of h.socket when i change url form my url it works fine . how can i fix it

Comment: A server can be configured to Require TLS or TLS optional.   So first you have to make sure you are comparing HTTP with HTTP; or HTTPS with HTTPS.  Second TLS is used for authentication before the request is sent.   When TLS fails (HTTPS) you do not get a response status like 404.  The request is never sent so you do not get any response.  You are getting a response.

Comment: How long before error occurs?  If 30 seconds it could indicate a proxy failure.  You may oeed a proxy and setting proxy in client to null could solve issue.  Only TLS 1.2 and 1.3 can be used.  Older version of TLS are now obsolete.  So adding the following static method in your code before calling library may solve issue : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;  Older version of Net may not support the TLS encryption mode.  So using Net 4.7.2 or later and using default TLS option will do the encryption using windows instead of Net.

Comment: @jdweng  i have added ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; but it not works . i have created local server and it also not connecting and got error 'The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format '

Comment: Looks like from other similar postings that you are sending HTTPS and the server isn't configured for HTTPS (TLS).  Try HTTP or upgrade the libraries to work with TLS